# problems downloading bcmwl-kernel-source

Tags: drivers, kernel

When running
`sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source`

```
[sudo] password for carter: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libllvm7
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,550 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 167321 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../bcmwl-kernel-source_6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb ...
Removing all DKMS Modules
Done.
Unpacking bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) over (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up bcmwl-kernel-source (6.30.223.271+bdcom-0ubuntu4) ...
Loading new bcmwl-6.30.223.271+bdcom DKMS files...
Building for 5.0.0-23-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.0.0-23-generic
Done.

wl:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.0.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Operation not permitted
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.0.0-23-generic
```

(Leaving out the previous firmware mention as I seemed to have fixed that problem)

the could not insert 'wl' permission denied is something I've looked up and can't seem to find an answer to. Any help is greatly appriciated.

Comment: `dkms status` and `uname -r` please edit you question for output.